# Getting the URL of the Calling Application

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jax-rs

When using JAX-RS is there a way of getting information about who is calling the webservice? Can we get the ip or url of the calling application? If so how do you do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should work on Weblogic (servlet container).

Once you get the `HttpServletRequest` via the `@Context`, you can access any of the methods of [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String showIP(@Context HttpServletRequest hsr) {
   return hsr.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

Note that there is no way to figure out what the real client IP address if there are any proxies in between.